# R - partial string matching for new variable

Tags: string, r, contains, matching, partial

I have quite a big dataset which has 2 text variables `A` and `B`. `length(A)` <= `length(B)`. `B` can be either variable `A` with some extra characters (without order) or can be totally different from `A`. So i need to to create new variable within my data table under this condition:
If `B` contains `A` then `C = TRUE`. I believe partial string matching is more suitable for me here than normal string comparison.

My dataframe example:

```
Home      Pick  
Barc      Barcelona 0  
F Munch   FC munchen   
Lakers    Portland
```

I need to add new variable Side in this way:

```
Home     Pick         Side    
Barc     Barcelona 0  True  
F Munch  FC munchen   True  
Lakers   Portland     False
```

i am trying to solve with this:

```
data_n$Side <- stringMatch(data_n$Home, data_n$Pick, normalize = "YES")
```

but it gives all negative results.
 Hoverer

```
stringMatch('barcel', 'Barcelona 0', normalize='YES')
```

gives needed answer. Any hints where i make mistake?

Comment: you should include any extra packages that you are using. `agrep` is a useful base solution for partial matching

Comment: doesn't stringMatch give a value within the interval of 0 to 1? by the way, using your dataset, I got a value of 0.444 for the dataframe and 0.545 for the single example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It actually doesn make such a big difference which funkction to use (agrep, stringmatch or any other). The problem is that i can not make it work on my 17000 rows data file. How should i do that?? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of its reliability, but `agrepl`, the partial pattern matching function, seems to work on your data.  Assume `dat` is your original data, then

```
## read in the original data
> txt <- "Home\tPick
  Barc\tBarcelona 0
  F Munch\tFC munchen
  Lakers\tPortland"
> dat <- read.table(text = txt, sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
##      Home        Pick
## 1    Barc Barcelona 0
## 2 F Munch  FC munchen
## 3  Lakers    Portland
```

using `agrepl`

```
> d1 <- dat[,1]
> d2 <- dat[,2]
> dat$Side <- sapply(seq(nrow(dat)), function(i){
      agrepl(d1[i], d2[i], ignore.case = TRUE)
      })
> dat
##      Home        Pick  Side
## 1    Barc Barcelona 0  TRUE
## 2 F Munch  FC munchen  TRUE
## 3  Lakers    Portland FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to be working from the first sight. As i undersand agrepl function is base funkcion and no additional packages are needed? I get error:
Error in FUN(1:17076[[1L]], ...) : could not find function "agrepl"

Comment: just updated R and works fine now. Not 100% accurate but still helped a lot! thanks